# How to preload interstitial ads - android studio?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

I created a small puzzle app, on completion of each level I wanted to display interstitial ads, but it is taking few seconds to load ads. So soon after the button is clicked it navigates to the next activity without showing ads. If I pause for few seconds and press the button it is showing ads. please help me out!

```
public class Completed extends AppCompatActivity {

InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

public void onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setMessage("Do you want to go to Home?");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //if user pressed "yes", then he is allowed to exit from application
            finish();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //if user select "No", just cancel this dialog and continue with app
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert=builder.create();
    alert.show();
}


private void requestNewInterstitial() {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .build();

    //AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_completed);

    requestNewInterstitial();
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            requestNewInterstitial();

        }
    });

    //requestNewInterstitial();

    Typeface MyTypeFace=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"comic.ttf");
    Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btncomplete);
    TextView txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtcomplete);
    btn.setTypeface(MyTypeFace);
    txt.setTypeface(MyTypeFace);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (MainActivity.setsound) {
                MainActivity.mp.start();
            }
            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();

            }
            finish();


        }
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

on app start call init method:

```
public void init()
    {
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(baseAppController);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(baseAppController.getString(R.string.interstitial_ad_unit_id));
        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed()
            {
                requestNewInterstitial();
            }
        });
        requestNewInterstitial();
    }
private void requestNewInterstitial()
    {
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(getAdRequest());
    }

    public AdRequest getAdRequest()
    {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                //.addTestDevice("SEE_YOUR_LOGCAT_TO_GET_YOUR_DEVICE_ID")
//                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .build();
        return adRequest;
    }
```

when you want to show ad just call below method:

```
public void showInterstitial()
    {
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded())
        {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdClosed() {
        requestNewInterstitial();

    }
public void onAdLoaded (){
//... your code is here
}
});
```

Comment: Which snippet should i place there?  finish(); or mInterstitialAd.show(); ?

Comment: @SathyaApps , if you want to show use InterstitialAd.show(); . I don't know what behavoiur you want.